# How to reload AnalyzingInfixSuggester from the directory?

Tags: lucene

Using lucene 5.4.1 I am trying to use the AnalyzingInfixSuggester to build a suggestion library and I'm running into an issue where I am unable to load that suggester.  I have one process that builds an index out of my data and I have another process(web service) that returns data by searching against that index.  However, when I try to open the index, I get nothing from suggester.getCount()

I am calling commit() on my suggester after writing to the directory.  On the file system, the files in the directory in question contain about 5.8M of data.  However, when I open it to make a search from the web service, I get nothing.  I tried calling build and refresh just in case I needed to do that to initialize and still get nothing.

I feel like I'm missing something.  Can someone please point me in the direction of some example code that actually reads the suggestion documents from a file system directory?

Comment: You can start with the lucene source and look in the test classes.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I could not see anything different from what I was doing, turns out the problem was me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I thought.  A compound of forgetting that my index was built on my machine while the service was running on a vagrant instance.  Wrote to a shared directory, removed calls to refresh and build and it works.  So to recap, all that is necessary is to construct the suggester by passing the directory and analyzer and it works as expected.